# Adafruit IO example won't compile, library required is correct version

Tags: adafruit

I have Arduino IDE 1.8.5 installed, and also Adafruit IO Arduino 2.6.0 and Adafruit MQTT Library 0.20.0.

With the Adafruit IO lib comes a set of examples, and I wanted to use example adafruitio_07_digital_out as a starting point for a project on an Adafruit HUZZAH ESP8266.

It won't compile. I get

```
#error "This sketch requires Adafruit MQTT Library v0.17.0 or higher. Please install or upgrade using the Library Manager."
```

which I find strange. I've tried installing 0.17.0 instead of 0.20.0, but that doesn't help.

Is there anything I can do to get this to work? The suggested solution of using the Library Manager to install the required package is obviously not working.

Comment: can you double check and confirm that the library you have installed is actually installed and is higher than the required version?

Comment: @EngrAbbas I don't know how to check that other than using Sketch->Include Library->Manage Libraries and I've been through there many many times by now. Anywhere else I should look?

Comment: @gibson - On Stack Exchange sites such as this answers are not to be edited into questions.  Remove that and post it instead in the answer form below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was that I had installed the Arduino IDE through the windows app store. Uninstalling it, downloading it through a browser, and using the same code works just fine.